# Create pdf for Rest web services with Springfox

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, springfox

I'm using Spring (not Spring boot), Maven and Springfox. With the last plugin I can show the web services documentation through URL `/swagger-ui.html` but I need a document to share. I read about `Swagger2Markup` so I have imported into pom file this dependecy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger2markup</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>jcenter-releases</id>
        <name>jcenter</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

At this point I have created a test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, SwaggerConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void convertSwaggerToAsciiDoc() throws Exception {
        String outputDir = ("C:/Users/Luca Calicchio/Downloads");
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
        String swaggerJson = response.getContentAsString();
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(outputDir));
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputDir, "swagger.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
            writer.write(swaggerJson);
        }
    }
}
```

This class creates a json file with the documentation and now I have to convert this file to pdf. I have not found a guide to make this step, only find this guideline

- generate an up-to-date Swagger JSON file during an unit or
  integration test
- convert the Swagger JSON file into AsciiDoc
- add hand-written AsciiDoc documentation
- convert AsciiDoc into HTML and PDF
- copy the HTML and PDF artifacts into an executable Spring Boot Jar
  file and serve it as static content

  Can you help me?

Comment: and did you face any issues following the guide? were you finally able to get the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution following this demo code:

```
https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/spring-swagger2markup-demo
```

Pay attention to `pom.xml` file where it configure all above steps